# Create javascript object (class) from django model

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, class

I am working on an single-page application that will load up data from about a dozen different django models, allow the user to manipulate the data, and then save all changes back to the database.

I can sort of 'pass' the django model to template by serializing a result from a queryset. For example, I have a model Person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Now, in my view, I can pass a "person" object to the template in json format by serializing it

```
person_object = serializers.serialize("json", Person.objects.filter(id=1))
```

Then, in my javascript:

```
var someperson = {{ data|safe }};
```

However, I would like to be able to create a "new" person on the client side, as if the Person were a javascript class not simply a json object:

```
var person2 = new Person(id=5,age=33m,name="john");
```

Is there a way for my javascript "class" to inherit the Django data model? Or do I need to manually re-create my data models between django and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the in a string as a whole

```
person = 'new Person(id="%(id)s",age="%(age)s",name="%(name)s")' %
 {'id':person_instance.id , ....}
```

then send it to the template as a context variable , so it look like this

```
var person2 = {{ person }} ;
```

Comment: That doesn't really fix the issue I'm having. I can get person "objects" from django to javascript without an issue. It is creating new objects on the client side that is problematic, since there is no corresponding "class" (function) in javascript that will allow me to construct new people objects.

Sure, I can technically mimic the data model manually, but that seems like a poor solution, since changes to the model will need to also be made in the javascript constructor.