# How to use a Django model for validation and form generation in client-side application?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

When designing a frontend webapp for a Django backend service, it would be nice to define the data model/validation code only once (using Django ORM).

- How can a Django data model be used to automatically generate (JavaScript) client-side forms and validation objects?
- Are there any notable projects or libraries bringing Django ORM/forms to client-side JavaScript frameworks?

Comment: This is similar to an unanswered SO question from 2014: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048314/create-javascript-object-class-from-django-model

Comment: Do you mean this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I am thinking of generic  'model forms' for a client-side single page app built with a JavaScript framework. E.g. the SPA could be built with Aurelia, Angular, Vue.js, etc.

Comment: My basic understanding is that to use Django backend with SPA frontend, we have to define our models twice. This means we have to sync changes between two model definitions. We also lose the power of model forms and possibly other benefits provided by Django.

Comment: I also realize that this is a "tall order", particularly with custom Python validators as they might have to be transpiled to JavaScript. I am basically interested to learn what would be involved with the general idea of sharing Django model/validation code with JavaScript client applications. Are there any ongoing projects or efforts related to these ideas?

Comment: I'm working on a JS <> REST bridge typically used with Django Rest Framework. Basically an object mapper, doesn't do validation (yet): https://github.com/maykinmedia/ConsumerJS

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such django library. Normally validation at the client side will require a JS library e.g. Parsely.js or validate.js (there are plenty!).

However, my experience is that you don't really need this if you want to keep your code simple, as you can set [custom form/model validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) in django directly, so that the form submitted will be rejected if any of the rules you specify are not met, and a custom error message displayed.

Nonetheless, the closest that I can think to what you might be looking for is the package [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has a superb api and allows you to set most of your form html and form logic directly from the server side.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question is related to using Django with a single-page app (SPA) framework, such as Aurelia, Angular, Vue, etc.. With SPA clients, the communication occurs, generally, over REST and WebSockets. So, we seem to lose some capabilities such as server-side-rendering (I.e. the Crispy Forms option). I would like to figure out how to share Django model validation and form generation capabilities with a client-side JavaScript SPA.

Comment: I understand. I don't know if a library for passing validation objects exist. My only idea is that perhaps you can serialise some of the validation parameters and pass them along with you form/model data and then plug them into a js function...

Answer (score 1):

Django restframework has all what you need to serialize a model quickly. Have a look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the question was misworded. I would like to use a Django model to generate a client-side validation object and possibly even input forms. That way, developers would maintain only one model definition, I.e. DRY.

Comment: Django form can use your model to generate the fields. Django RFM can do the same to generate you the serialization. The Django model has a clean facility for the validation that can be used in the derivate form and serializer

Comment: How can I send the generated form to a client-side single page application framework, such as Angular, Aurelia, or Vue?

Comment: If with 'generated form' you mean the result of form.as_p() or other similar methods available in the form class, you can just modify your view to handle the request with a different template if "request.is_ajax == True" depend on how you built your app

Comment: This is not what he asked

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but model validation can be pushed to the client by using https://johnfraney.github.io/django-front-end-validators/

I would ideally fork this and implement what my project requires since this project is not mature enough for the projects I work in.